# Vaadin maven compile themes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin7

If I try to run in eclipse maven vaadin:compile-theme I get:

[WARNING] Vaadin plugin could not find any themes.

[INFO] No themes found. Use the parameter "vaadin.theme" to explicitly select a theme.

I have some themes in my project, how can i specify them?
I'm not sure how to do it correcty, can somebody help me?

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.or /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>erion</groupId>
  <artifactId>erion</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>erion</name>
  <description>an administration tool for stores</description>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.3.5</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
          Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

          For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
          compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
          explicit dependency.
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.peimari</groupId>
            <artifactId>dawn</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                    <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                        way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <!-- Most Vaadin apps don't need this stuff, guide that to target -->
                    <persistentunitcachedir>${project.build.directory}</persistentunitcachedir>
                    <deploy>${project.build.directory}/gwt-deploy</deploy>
                    <!-- Compile report is not typically needed either, saves hunreds of mb disk -->
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>

                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                                </modules> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [7.3.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.widgetsetNature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.widgetsetBuilder</buildcommand>
                            <buildcommand>com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.addonStylesBuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in properties tag :

```
<vaadin.theme>YOUR_VAADIN_THEME</vaadin.theme>
```

Replace *YOUR_VAADIN_THEME* by the value you put in @Theme() annotation.
It will give you something like this :

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.or /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>erion</groupId>
  <artifactId>erion</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>erion</name>
  <description>an administration tool for stores</description>

  <properties>
        <vaadin.theme>YOUR_VAADIN_THEME</vaadin.theme>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.3.5</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score -1):

in ur web.xml
add

```
<context-param>
<description>Vaadin production mode</description>
<param-name>productionMode</param-name>
<param-value>${productionMode}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and in ur 
pom.xml

```
<properties>
<productionMode>false</productionMode>

</properties>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The op asked how to explicitly set a theme. You describe how to configure the production-mode.